# Find good days to rob the bank - some test cases failing

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I came across the LeetCode problem [2100. Find Good Days to Rob the Bank](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-good-days-to-rob-the-bank/):

> You and a gang of thieves are planning on robbing a bank. You are given a **0-indexed** integer array `security`, where `security[i]` is the number of guards on duty on the `i`<sup>th</sup> day. The days are numbered starting from `0`. You are also given an integer `time`.
>
> The `i`<sup>th</sup> day is a good day to rob the bank if:
>
> - There are at least `time` days before and after the `i`<sup>th</sup> day,
> - The number of guards at the bank for the `time` days **before** `i` are **non-increasing**, and
> - The number of guards at the bank for the `time` days **after** `i` are **non-decreasing**.
>   More formally, this means day `i` is a good day to rob the bank if and only if `security[i - time] >= security[i - time + 1] >= ... >= security[i] <= ... <= security[i + time - 1] <= security[i + time]`.
>
> Return *a list of **all** days **(0-indexed)** that are good days to rob the bank. The order that the days are returned in does **not** matter.*

The solution, that I created seems fine to me. Not sure, where I am going wrong with some test cases failing.

```
class Solution(object):
    def goodDaysToRobBank(self, security, time):
        """
        :type security: List[int]
        :type time: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        total_guards = len(security)
        if time == 0:
            return [i for i in range(total_guards)]
        
        left = [1]*total_guards
        right = [1]*total_guards
        l_pattern_found = False
        r_pattern_found = False
        
        for i in range(1, total_guards):
            if security[i-1] >= security[i]:
                left[i] = left[i-1] + 1
                l_pattern_found = True

                
        for i in range(total_guards-2, -1, -1):
            if security[i+1] >= security[i]:
                right[i] = right[i+1] + 1
                r_pattern_found = True

            
        if not l_pattern_found or not r_pattern_found:
            return []
        
        days = []
        for i in range(time, total_guards-time):
            if left[i-1] >= time and right[i+1] >= time:
                days.append(i)
                
        return days
```

Here is what I have done:

- Compute the left prefix for the condition mentioned
- Compute the right prefix for the condition mentioned
- Find the days in the range [time, n-time]

This is failing for the test case as follows:

```
security = [1,2,5,4,1,0,2,4,5,3,1,2,4,3,2,4,8]
time = 2
```

The expected output is: `[5,10,14]` and my output is `[4,5,6,10,14]`

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: @MrSmith42 I have updated the failing test case. Sorry, missed adding it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is in this line:

```
        if left[i-1] >= time and right[i+1] >= time:
```

Here the value of `left[i-1]` does not guarantee that the current value at `security[i]` is not greater than `security[i-1]`. To ensure that, you would need to look at `left[i]` instead of `left[i-1]`. For the same reason you should be looking at `right[i]` instead of `right[i+1]`. But that means you need to reduce all counts by 1, and initialise your `left` and `right` lists with zeroes:

```
    left = [0]*total_guards
    right = [0]*total_guards
```

With those corrections it will work.